# Google maps JavaScript data_layer multiple styles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 3 Polygons in google maps javascript initialized like this:

```
map.data.add({geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path), google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path2), ])})
map.data.add({geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path2), google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path3), ])})
map.data.add({geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path3) ])})
```

I set the style with this code:

```
 map.data.setStyle({
           strokeColor: '#FF0000',
           strokeOpacity: 0.8,
           strokeWeight: 2,
           fillColor: '#FF0000',
           fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
```

This sets the style of all 3 Polygon´s. But how can I set a different style for each polygon?

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option for styling the polygons differently is to give them unique properties that determine the style.  For example:

```
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path)]),
    properties: {
      color: 'blue'
    }
  })
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path2)]),
    properties: {
      color: 'green'
    }
  })
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path3)]),
    properties: {
      color: 'orange'
    }
  });
```

Then create a styling function that uses that property to set the style (modified from the Google example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic):

```
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var color = feature.getProperty('color');
    return /** @type {!google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ ({
      fillColor: color,
      strokeColor: color,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uhjopvcz/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

[proof of concept with nested polygons](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uhjopvcz/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map (with nested polygons)]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
  })
  var pathCoords = [{lat: 37.4687,lng: -122.151627},
    {lat: 37.453575,lng: -122.165704},
    {lat: 37.453575,lng: -122.141156}
  ];
  var pathCoords2 = [{lat: 37.437902,lng: -122.174802},
    {lat: 37.425089,lng: -122.182355},
    {lat: 37.425225,lng: -122.163987}
  ];
  var pathCoords3 = [{lat: 37.431087,lng: -122.103562},
    {lat: 37.415409,lng: -122.114549},
    {lat: 37.415954,lng: -122.096009}
  ];

  function convert2LatLng(input) {
    var pathLatLng = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(input[i].lat, input[i].lng);
      pathLatLng.push(pt);
    }
    return pathLatLng;
  }

  var path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(convert2LatLng(pathCoords));
  var path2 = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(convert2LatLng(pathCoords2));
  var path3 = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(convert2LatLng(pathCoords3));
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path)]),
    properties: {
      color: 'blue'
    }
  })
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path2)]),
    properties: {
      color: 'green'
    }
  })
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path3)]),
    properties: {
      color: 'orange'
    }
  });
  // Color each letter gray. Change the color when the isColorful property
  // is set to true.
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var color = feature.getProperty('color');
    return /** @type {!google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ ({
      fillColor: color,
      strokeColor: color,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```